# Time still show up in date datatype

Tags: c#, winforms, date, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database table with a datatype of `date` not the `datetime`. But still in my Crystal Report it appears like this:

```
 8/4/2013  12:00:00AM
 8/2/2013  12:00:00AM
 8/1/2013  12:00:00AM
```

12:00:00AM must not included because the datatype is `date` not the `datetime` right? Why is it still shows up in the report? How I will remove that?

Answer (score 1):

That is because with few exceptions<sup>**1**</sup>, [SQL Server date/time datatypes are mapped to `DateTime`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx). If you don't want to see a time component, specify an appropriate [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) [string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to get the desired display format. For instance,

```
string today = new DateTime(2013,8,1).ToString("d MMM yyyy") ;
```

will give you a value of `1 Aug 2013` (in an English language culture).

<sup>**1**</sup> The `time` data type is mapped to a `TimeSpan`, and `datetimeoffset` is mapped to...wait for it...`DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: that format string would be in formula of column in the SQL SERVER?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the field

Click Format Editor

In display string formula write this:

```
ToText(date({TableName.DateColumn}))
```